# Css div not aligning properly

Tags: css, html, xhtml, alignment

I have some pretty simple CSS code that doesn't seem to be working right...

```
html, body { border:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: url(../img/bg-tile.png) repeat; color: #444}

.content{
    background-color:#CCDDEE;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.column{
    padding:0% 2% 0% 0%;
    width:29%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}

.myText{
    padding:0px 25% 0px 0px;
    font-size:16px;
}

.footer{
    margin-bottom:2%;
    padding:0px;
    position: absolute;
}

.wrapper { 
    width:75%;
    height:auto;
    margin:1% auto; 
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <!--Snipped some code Just a nav -->
        <br /><br />
        <div class="content">
            <img src="img/slider6.jpg" alt="" /><br /><br />
            <div class="column">
                <p class="myText">
                Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text,
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <p class="myText">
                Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text,
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            <p class="myText">
                Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text, Testing some text,
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        &copy;2013 blahblahblah&reg; | Terms of Use | Privacy Policy | Press Inquiries
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

The issue that I'm having is that my foot is sitting on top of my "columns"  like so (image incoming)

[image: Text overlap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow:hidden;` to the `.content` will make the `.content` correctly *contain* the floating elements. That will also make the background colour apply to the floating columns.

If you don't want the `.content` to *contain* the floated elements, add `overflow:hidden;` to the `.wrapper` instead.

The problem you are seeing is because of the `float` on the columns. CSS float takes the element out of normal flow and therefore the containing element's height will not take the floated element's height into consideration when being rendered.

Therefore the footer will be rendered after the content (correctly) but the `.content` has the wrong height.

An alternate way to do this is to `clear` the floated content - see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ and [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)